# How to covert number 100.00 to currency format (100,00 $US) for Locale.CANADA_FRENCH?

Tags: java, currency

How to covert number 100.00 to currency format (100,00 $ US) for Locale.CANADA_FRENCH?

I have a scenario where I have to convert number 100.00 to currency format in Locale.CANADA_FRENCH.
At the same time I need the currency to be in USD. i.e the currency symbol should be like "$US".

I can't do any hardcoding like appending country code,
Please let me know if there is a way to get the this by passing locale or Currency code any method.
And we are using Java 8

Till now I have tried below things,

```
String amount = "100.00";
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.CANADA_FRENCH);
format.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance("USD"));
System.out.println(format.format(new BigDecimal(amount)));
```

Output we get is 100,00 USD

```
String amount = "100.00";
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.CANADA_FRENCH);
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) format;
df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().setCurrency(Currency.getInstance("USD"));

System.out.println(format.format(new BigDecimal(amount)));
```

Output we get is 100,00 $

Comment: what you ask for is already exist but for jdk 9 the closet i get is that
`System.out.println(format.format(new BigDecimal(amount))+format.getCurrency().getSymbol()); `

it print 
`100,00 USD$` 
hope someone else get better way for jdk 8

Comment: look at this something similar for your question https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-format-a-number-as-currency-depending-on-locale-in-java

Comment: Thank you, Jason0011, but it's the same code which I have tried,

Thanks @justsomeone, but I can't do concatenation because when Currency code changes, for ex: CAD, output should be something like CA$162.31.
Could you please kindly help on how to achieve this in Java 9.

Comment: using your first code example you simply run it with jdk 9 or above i just used jdk 17 and the output is `100,00 $ US` run your code here https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler-ide/ and see the difference when you choose different jdk